# How to Check the Value on "UITextField with tag" that which Textfield tag is pressed/Touch or Clicked?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have The following code...

```
for (j=0; j<20; j++) {

    if (j<20) {



    txtField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, txt_Pos_Y, 100, 15)];
    txtField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    txtField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11];
    txtField.tag = j;
    txtField.placeholder = @"Enter Value";
    txtField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    txtField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;

    txtField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    txtField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    txtField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;    
    txtField.delegate = self;
    [scrollView addSubview:txtField];
    [txtField release];      


    txt_Pos_Y  = txt_Pos_Y  + 20; 
    }
```

The code creates 20 textfields....All Textfields are editable when view will load.Now I want to give value.I want, on which textfield I click First, only that TextField will be editable and Rest will be NonEditable.

I gave the tag , txtField.tag = j;

now i am not able to figure out that which tag is pressed or clicked? And not able To make the TextField editable which i clicked First, and rest Non-Editable?

I tried this to check the condition in CalculateMethod() method that txtField.tag == 1 is clicked but this is not working.

```
-(void)CalculateMethod {
UITextField *txtFld = (UITextField*)[scrollView viewWithTag:1];


// I want if TextFeild "txtField.tag == 1"  is clicked then Enter this condition 
if(txtField.tag == 1){      
double a;
a = Var_sqFt * Var_sqMtr;
txtFld.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.4f",a];
} 


// I want if TextFeild "txtField.tag == 2"  is clicked then Enter this condition 
if(txtField.tag == 2){     // Here I want Only that 
double a;
a = Var_sqFt * Var_sqMtr;
txtFld.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.4f",a];
} 

}
```

So  I have 2 questions

1. I want, on which textfield I click First, only that TextField will be editable and Rest will be NonEditable , how to do this?
2. Which TextField is clicked/Touch/Pressed , Like I tried in CalculateMethod() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To check which field started editing**

You should look into the `Delegate` methods for your `UITextField`s. Simply set the delegate of all fields to `self` i.e. the controller creating the textFields. Then implement the `UITextField` delegate method

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField*)textField;
```

in the method check the tag of incoming parameter `textField` to perform your task.

**To enable disable fields**

Put all your fields in an `NSMutableArray`, iterate the array and only enable the field which matches the delegate parameter. Disable the rest.

Comment: Sir same thing I want to do "in the method check the tag of incoming parameter textField to perform your task." How to Check the Tag? I tried, if(txtfeild.tag == 1){....Something....}  , this condition not execute and the compiler doesnot enter in this condition even I enter the value on "txtfeild.tag = 1"

Comment: It should work. Try logging the tag values by using `NSLog(@"The TAG is %i", textField.tag);` to make sure you have right `if` condition

Answer (score 0):

`[scrollView viewWithTag:1]` will always give you the subview with tag `1` which is the same textView following your snippet. If you want to go through all the textViews you can do it with

```
for (UIView* aSubview in [self.scrollView subviews])
{
    if ([aSubview isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]])
    {
            UITextView * typedTextViewSubview = aSubview;
            switch (typedTextViewSubview.tag)
            {
            case 1 : {
               double a;
               a = Var_sqFt * Var_sqMtr;
               typedTextViewSubview.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.4f",a];


             }
       .......
            }

    }
}
```

And you do not really need `if (j<20)` check as you already have given 20 as conditional upper limit of `j` iteration.

Comment: Sir i want to know that which Textfiled tag is clicked?How to know that?

Comment: @Areeba Khan For that you've got an answer above, mine is hopefully a little helper for your future work. As another answer says, you use the delegate methods to get the touched textView as a sender (caste to class `id`) and all the other textView you can get with a little loop from my answer or you can store all of them in the array to save the search time. Hope it helps.

Comment: As another answer says, you use the delegate methods to get the touched textView as a sender (caste to class id) and all the other textView you can get with a little loop from my answer or you can store all of them in the array to save the search time. How to do this?

Comment: @Areeba Khan first you'll want to set the textViews delegate, you can do it at `Interface Builder` or at `viewDidLoad` if you have the outlet property at the view controller. Usually for the textViews the viewController itself is used as a delegate, so you'll want to select the `file owner` at `IB` or `tv.delegate = self;` at `viewDidLoad`